# Get all elements working in a same page with same id/class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have been using some carousel for my page there is 3 carousel on that page the carousel has `#carousel` each :

### No-1

```
  <ul id="#carousel">
      <li><img ..../>
      ......
  <ul>
```

### no -2

```
  <ul id="#carousel">
      <li><img ..../>
      ......
  <ul>
```

### no - 3

```
  <ul id="#carousel">
      <li><img ..../>
      ......
  <ul>
```

when i am applying owlcarousel to the three elements the first one is working and and remainings are not working

```
$("#carousel").owlCarousel({
   autoPlay: 3000
});
```

What is the solution?

Comment: Elements' IDs inside document must be unique, according to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/id), but you can select multiple elements with same ID using `$('[id="carousel"]')` if you somewhy can't change HTML code.

Comment: @Regent: i used to suggest that solution when joined SO. but realized that you should never encourage people to break the rules. IDs should be unique. Always..

Comment: @MilindAnantwar that's for sure. And that's why I edited comment: _if you somewhy can't change HTML code_

Comment: @Regent :  agreed :)

Answer (score 1):

IDs should be unique. `$("#carousel")` will only target first element in matched selector. You can rather use common class to ul and class selector to target them using jquery:

**MarkUp:**

```
<ul class="carousel">
  <li><img ..../>
  ......
<ul>
```

**Script:**

```
$(".carousel").owlCarousel({
  autoPlay: 3000
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the same id for multiple instances, how about this (assuming you do not have other `ul`):

```
 $("ul").owlCarousel({
    autoPlay: 3000
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead of ID here because ID must be unique.

```
$(".carousel").owlCarousel({
   autoPlay: 3000
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="carousel">
   <li><img ..../>
   ......
<ul>
```